# Jquery UI resizable with data event cloning

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm having a strange issue with jquery ui, with resize and then cloning with data events set to true.

For example inside my div I have multiple divs with click and hover events, but the parent div can be cloned and resized.using clone(true) and jquery ui resize().

The issue arrises when on the cloned item resize stops working all together, does anyone know a way to fix this. Suggestions like remove ui handle, add a specific id to each clone, destroy the instance and re apply it do not seem to work.

I've added a small example on jsFiddle of what I'm trying to achieve.

https://jsfiddle.net/pat3wzgp/3/

```
<div class="resizable">
    <h1 class="clickEvent">Click Me</h1>
    <button class="cloneMap">Clone Now!</button>
    <button class="cloneMap2">Clone Two!</button>
</div>

<div class="inserts">

</div>
```

(function(){

```
/**
* Resize with clone data events issue jquery UI
*/
$('.resizable').resizable();

$('.clickEvent').click(function(){
    $('.inserts').append('<p>Clicked</p>');
});

$('.cloneMap').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var cloned_data = $(this).parent().clone(true);
    //clone and insert after parent.
    cloned_data.insertAfter($(this).parent());
});

$('.cloneMap2').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    /**
    *Removing the handle still fails
    */
    var cloned_data = $(this).parent().clone(true);
    cloned_data.find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove().end().resizable();

    //clone and insert after parent.
    cloned_data.insertAfter($(this).parent());
});

/**
* If you set with dataEvents to false like : .clone(false), remove the resizable
* and re add it then it works, however you've just removed data events, so any
* hover or click functionality will be lost. 
*/

}());
```

Thanks,
Martyn

Comment: the `resizable` widget relies on element-specific data. `.clone(true)` doesn't know or care about this. The usual way to handle this is to use `.clone(false)`, then initialise a new widget on the cloned element (what you've mentioned in the comment -- the second click handler will do exactly that if you remove the `true` from `clone`). Re-bind the event handlers, or use event delegation, for additional events

Comment: Yeah, thats how I've got around it, but seems such an inefficient way to do things. I've basically added everything to a loader function then recall the loader function on clone using $(this) for specifics. I was hoping i could avoid this method though.